# Wordpress not working after AWS public ip and public DNS changed

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-route53

I accidentally added an Elastic IP to my instance, which is doing wordpress hosting.  Now the old address(old public IP ) override by new address and I am not able to access wordpress page.

What can I do to reverse these change? If not can i  make amendments to change ip address in the wordpress, so that wordpress can get it running again.

i already try this with no luck https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Suggestions are appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Why would changing the IP address stop it working? Wordpress doesn't care about IP addresses. Can you access it by IP address? What do you mean "old address overrides the new address" - do you mean IP or host name? You really need to explain what you did more clearly.

Comment: Change the DNS maybee?

Comment: @Tim thank you for reply , I use the elastic IP , and now the public IP changed to the elastic IP. consequently i am no able to access by public DNS(aws provide) and public IP.

Comment: @Orphans Hi Orphans thankyou for reply, AWS DNS is fixed , i am not able to change that.

Comment: @Fenici Alright, so the external IP does get routed to the wrong internal IP?

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. You shouldn't use the default assigned public IPs for anything, they can change if your instance reboots. Are you saying DNS has the old public IP address and you can't access the website by domain name? Can you see your website if you type the elastic IP in? I assume you've updated DNS with the new elastic IP address.

Comment: Can you add some very specific details as to what exactly is not working anymore? When you go to your wordpress site now, what happens? What errors do you see?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have assigned an Elastic IP address to an EC2 instance, any previous public IP address is gone. It goes back into the pool of public IP addresses for other people to use and it cannot be recovered.

So at this point, stop using the public IP address because it may already be assigned to someone else's EC2 instance.

Your EC2 instance has an Elastic IP address now. Use it and embrace it.

1. When accessing your EC2 instance by an IP address, use the Elastic IP address.
2. When accessing your EC2 instance by the AWS public DNS name, use the new one based off the Elastic IP address.
3. If you had DNS records (eg. in Route 53, GoDaddy, etc.) pointing to the old public IP address, then change them all to point to the new Elastic IP address. Depending on the TTL settings of the DNS records, it may take upto 48 hours for the new DNS values to propogate.
4. If your WordPress website had the old Public IP address in it's configuration, change it to the Elastic IP address.

The main thing is to stop lamenting about the old Public IP address. It's gone and you will never get it back. So start using the Elastic IP address.

Comment: Thanks for reply , i understand, i am not able to recover my original address , but what can i do to get ride of \ the old ip address in the wordpress and input the new address. so i can get my wordpress running ?